# Making an interactive chart in Altair with change on click

Tags: python, charts, altair

I am trying to create an interactive chart in Altair in Jupyter lab. This is my dataframe

```
data = {
    'Group_1': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
    'Group_2': ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Pink", "Brown", "Black"],
    'Group_1_value': [99, 98, 95, 90, 56, 34, 56],
    'Group_2_value': [4, 34, 12, 33, 32, 13, 21]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

First, I want to create a chart for Group_1 category and the corresponding value. Like this
[image]

then, I want to be able to click on either A or B bar - which would change the graph to sub categories within Group_2 corresponding to A and B respectively. For example, if I click on A, it should turn to this graph

[image]

***the problem I am facing is I am not able to do this in one graph only- I end with 2 side by side graphs or one graph with all values as you can see in the two images below. How to achieve this?***

[image]
[image]

this is the code i used for the two above images.

```
# Create a selection
click = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Group_1'])

# Create the bar chart for Group_1 and Group_1_value
chart_group_1 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Group_1:N',
    y='mean(Group_1_value):Q',
    color=alt.condition(click, 'Group_1:N', alt.value('lightgray')),
    tooltip=['Group_1', 'mean(Group_1_value)']
).properties(
    width=300,
    title='Bar Chart for Group_1 and Group_1_value'
).add_selection(
    click
)

# Create the subcategories chart for Group_2 and Group_2_value
chart_group_2 = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Group_2:N',
    y='mean(Group_2_value):Q',
    color='Group_2:N',
    tooltip=['Group_2', 'mean(Group_2_value)']
).transform_filter(
    click
).properties(
    width=300,
    title='Subcategories for Group_1'
)

# Combine both charts
final_chart = alt.hconcat(chart_group_1, chart_group_2)

final_chart
```

and

```
# Create a selection
click = alt.selection_multi(fields=['Group_1'])

# Create the chart
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Group_1:N',
    y='mean(Group_1_value):Q',
    color=alt.condition(click, 'Group_1:N', alt.value('lightgray')),
    tooltip=['Group_1', 'mean(Group_1_value)']
).properties(
    width=400,
    title='Group_1 Bars (Click to expand)'
)

# Create a subcategories layer for Group_2
subcategories = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='Group_2:N',
    y='mean(Group_2_value):Q',
    color='Group_2:N',
    tooltip=['Group_2', 'mean(Group_2_value)']
).transform_filter(
    click
)

# Combine both layers
final_chart = chart + subcategories

final_chart.add_selection(click)
```